# How can I bind DataGrid row count after a CollectionView filter is applied?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, collectionviewsource

Previously to implementing filtering on the CollectionView, i used this to display the number of rows within the datagrid;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" />
```

I have since implemented a filter as so;

```
ICollectionView cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(datagrid1.ItemsSource);
cvs.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterMethod);
...
public bool FilterMethod(object item) {
    // conditionally returns true/false
}
```

The TextBlock above still shows the *unfiltered* count, when visually the filter is removing items from view.  How can I get the TextBlock above to show the row count as a result of the filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the filter is applied only on the collection view, and not on the item source.

You can do one of 2 thing:

1. bind to the collection view count (make sure its INPC).
2. bind to the items control items.count property.

This way the count will be same as what the user see.