# Determining the number of filtered rows in a CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf

I thought that this would be simple, maybe it is.

I want to know the number of rows in a CollectionViewSource after filtering has been applied (not the total number of rows  in the source).

Is there a property for this? Do I have to calculate this during the Filter event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499903/how-to-get-items-count-from-collectionviewsource)

"You could also do `_viewSource.View.Cast<object>().Count()` for the filtered list and `_viewSource.View.SourceCollection.Cast<object>().Count()` for the original."
-@rhyek

Comment: But I couldn't bind to that from XAML. I want a label to be bound to that value

Comment: Looks like you need to make a Dependency Property, which I'm not very good at to be honest.

Comment: [Maybe this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609953/how-can-i-bind-datagrid-row-count-after-a-collectionview-filter-is-applied)  Bind to the Object that displays you CollectionViewSouce with the Items.Count Property instead of ItemsSouce.Count. (Assuming that's what you're doing)

Comment: I went with this solution: _viewSource.View.Cast<object>().Count(). I run it after each load or filtering action. Assign the value to something in my viewmodel to which I bind. Too bad that a CollectionViewSource doesn't have a Count property that you can easily bind to.